# a.b=c; when it will throw NullPointerException? where a, b & c all are objects

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have a line in my Java code:

```
a.b=c;
```

Where `a`, `b` & `c` all are objects.

When the line will throw `NullPoinnterException`? When `a` is `null`, `b` is `null` or `c` is `null` or which combination of it is `null`?

Comment: What language is this? Since you say "a, b & c are all objects". Do you mean "intended to be objects", since NULL is not (in my opinion) an object...

Comment: I believe only when `a` is null. If `c` is null, then you are just saving that null value to `b`, which shouldn't be an issue. Now, if you had `c.Something` and `c` is null, then you also have an issue.

Comment: Pleased edit your question to add a tag indicating what language you're using. It's impossible to answer without that information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement `a.b = c` will throw a NullPointerException in the following instances:

1. When `a` is null.
2. If `b` is a primitive type (for example, int) and `c` is a type that can be autoboxed (unboxed in this case) to become that primitive type (for example, Integer) and `c` is null.
3. If there is an aop point cut that triggers and something in the point cut throws a NullPointerException.

The statement `a.b = c` will never throw a NullPointerException in the following instances:

1. `b` is null.
2. `c` is null and there is no autoboxing.

Answer (score 2):

If it's Java, it will throw only when `a` is null.

Answer (score -2):

In Java a NullPointerException will be thrown any time the reference on the left hand side of the dot operator is null.  In your example of "a.b=c" the only way for that expression to throw NullPointerException is if a is null.  If c is null and later you try to interact with a.b, that will throw a NullPointerException, but that would be consistent with what I just said.  When you interact with a.b with something like "a.b.number=42", if "a.b" is null, that will throw a NullPointerException.  The first sentence in this comment sums it up.  I hope that helps.